# How to delete last element and make return it in queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I want to delete(dequeue) last element in queue and return it's copy. My Second question is how to add element at beginning of the queue. This is my code

```
template <class TData>
TData Queue<TData>::GetBack()
{
    std::string err = "Queue is empty!";
    if(IsEmpty())
    {
        throw err;
    }
    else
    {
        TData pom = head->date;
        if(head->ptr == NULL)
        {
            delete head;
            head = tail = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            pNode pomm = head;
            head = head->ptr;
            delete pomm;
        }
        return pom;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is TDate? It is never decalred.

Comment: This is a method public method.

Comment: I assume head points to the last element pushed on the queue.  If so, doesn't your code work as it is already written?  A bit hard to tell without a [mcve].